# Gspread library function worksheet.findall('string') isn't working properly

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api, gspread

I Was wondering if anyone using gspread for google sheets api.
When I run worksheet.findall('string'), it only returns the matched cells in the very first column that the cells were encountered in.
For example, my column 9 has a cell called 'hi' & column 10 also has a cell called 'hi'. It returns only the col9 cell since col9 cell was encountered first.
Anyone can help please?

It should've returned all the matched cells with 'hi' when I run worksheet.findall('string') byt this isn't happening.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input situation you expect as the image, and provide the sample output value you expect?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.